# question on correlationId in the Azure activity log schema

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-eventhub, activitylog

Whether sent to Azure storage or Event Hub, the Activity log data share the same schema. One of the fields in the logs is correlationId. Events that share a correlationId belong to the same uber action. Can someone share an example of what is an uber action here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity Logs tracks management plane operations going through Azure Resource Manager (ARM). If you deploy a template, all the records generated from the template execution will share the same CorrelationId.